# Is there a way to find most voted questions from a certain time period?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, voting

Is there a way to find most voted questions from a certain time period, e.g from the last month? Now I can find a tag and then select "Votes" but AFAICS this is list of "all time most voted".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 10,000+ reputation or are a diamond moderator, this is available in the moderator tools section.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think it would be a good idea to get this available for all users.

Answer (score 3):

If you know sql, or are willing to learn, check out https://data.stackexchange.com/ - it contains a relatively recent copy of the site, with some things (like voting records) removed.

You can use a little SQL to find something similar to what you need - such as highest voted posts that were originally created during a specific time period.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine these search operators didn't exist when this question was posted but [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to restrict the search to posts last active or created within a specific date range.

So searching for [`is:question created:2013-10-21..2013-11-20`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is:question%20created:2013-10-21..2013-11-20) and selecting the "Votes" tab will bring back the top voted questions in the last month (at the time of writing).