# How to view "top voted questions for the day"?

Tags: support, questions, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find most voted questions from a certain time period?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94750/is-there-a-way-to-find-most-voted-questions-from-a-certain-time-period)

I'm looking for a way to look at questions with maximum vote increase for a given day, or even a daily digest of questions sorted by number of votes that day.

Comment: @ Jason_vorhees: Become 10k user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 10k, the `stats` tab in the `/tools` page will show you a list of highly upvoted and downvoted questions and answers. The only other way to get this info (if you're under 10k) is to use the API and sort them yourself. Here is how the page looks right now:

[image]

Comment: If we don't have 10k then?

Comment: *"The only other way to get this info (if you're under 10k) is to use the API and sort them yourself."* Considering there's no edit history, this was probably there when you posted that comment...

Comment: hmm through API only... time to write my own app then :) Thanks!

Comment: though on a related note, is there a way to filter out all questions below a certain number of votes?

Comment: @hawk when you have a follow-up question, you should ask it as a new question; not many people will see a comment and it's basically impossible to search for/find comments again later