# Best questions of specific time period

Tags: support, statistics

I was wondering if there is a way to look at the most upvoted questions of a tag in a certain time period, say last week or last month. I could, for example, look at the most upvoted questions of all time of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag by going to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=votes, but how do I only get those results of last month?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94750

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hottest *answers* in the last month are easily reached from [the tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/hot?filter=month)

To find the highest voted *questions* you can search for

```
[r] is:question created:2013-10-20..2013-11-20
```

Then [order by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Br%5D%20is:question%20created:2013-10-20..2013-11-20)

See the [advanced search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for details of the full search syntax supported.